# Can't put downloaded apps in my SD card

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, sd-card

I have a LG Tribute 5 with 8 Gigabytes of total memory. I had been getting the annoying box that says "Storage space running out". I bought an SD card and put all my pictures and music in it.

For some reason I am unable to move certain apps to my SD card. When I attempt to download apps from Google Play Store, it says "Not enough space" and gives me a list of apps to delete. Most of the apps on the list are in my SD card already. When I go to my settings and try to move all my downloaded apps to my SD card, a couple of them won't. For those couple apps, the option to "Move to SD card" is greyed out, signaling that moving to my SD card is not an option.

This is getting pretty annoying. Does anybody know what I can do to relieve this problem?

Comment: Google Play downloads apps to the internal storage first before installing them, so if you haven't got enough room on your internal, they cannot be installed. As for being unable to move apps to the SD card, it is up to the developer whether they want the app to be able to be installed on the SD card or not, a restriction which can be bypassed with root access.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of what your storage space looks like. As @Sonickyle27 suggested. The apps are first downloaded to your internal storage before being moved to your SD card and if your internal storage is still full, you won't be able to download the apps.

Answer (score 1):

> It's not always possible to move an app to an external SD Card via the
>   Application Manager.

There is a feature, called Flex Storage, that allows you to use an **external SD Card** as **Internal storage**. This can be done from **Settings** > **Storage** > **SD Card**, depending to your phone model. Remember that usually this operation formats your SD, so make sure to make a backup first. 
By the way, *this option is not supported from all devices*.

Another way to achieve the result is using a third-party software like [Link2SD](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.buak.Link2SD&hl=en) that allows you to move the apllications to a special partition on your SD Card and use them as usual. *Keep in mind that this operation requires **Root Privileges** on your phone.*

There are plenty of guides on the internet about this procedure, by the way I suggest you to **perform it only if you are sure**, because an error while executing the procedure (*especially when partitioning the SD*) can lead to data loss.